# What is the default ownership and permission for /usr?

Tags: permissions

I was moving a folder to `/usr/share/`, and I accidentally moved `/usr/share/` to my Desktop. I have since moved it back, but when I was in the live ISO, I stupidly changed the ownership of `/usr/` to the active user to avoid using the terminal. When I finished changed it back to `root`. However, the permissions are now screwed up. I tried using `sudo`, but it was broken. I followed [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452860/usr-bin-sudo-must-be-owned-by-uid-0-and-have-the-setuid-bit-set) and used

```
chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
```

but there are still things that don't work. I don't know the default permissions / ownership of `/usr/`. Can you help me?

Edit: To clarify, when I changed the permissions of /usr/ I changed also all the sub-directories

Comment: You say you changed the permissions of `/usr`. How did you do that and manage to affect the program `/usr/bin/sudo`? Do you mean you changed the permissions of `/usr` and every file/directory under it? Please [edit] your question to clarify this.

Comment: Are you running any particular Unix? Did you also change the ownership of all files _under_ `/usr`? If you changed ownership, then why are you trying to remedy it using `chmod`?

Comment: The default is what is recorded in the installed package. But I don't think it's easy into restore. May be boot into a Live system and reinstall those packages will help

Answer (score -1):

```
drwxr-xr-x. 13 root root 155 Nov 16 05:56 /usr/
```

Comment: This may well depend on what Unix the user is using. What you are showing is different from what would be correct on OpenBSD or macOS, for example. We don't know what Unix the user is using, so the question can't really be answered with finality.